# Asignar className dependiendo de una propp

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

Estoy creando un componente reutilizable y una de sus características que deseo agregar es que el color de fondo pueda ser definido con una propiedad.

En este momento, mi componente se ve así:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Row, Col } from 'reactstrap'

class Objetivo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="objetivos-portada">
        <Col className={'bg-dark text-light p-3'}>
          <h4 className="text-white">{this.props.title}</h4>
        </Col>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Pero la className `bg-dark` está fija.

Yo quiero llamar así al componente:

```
<Objetivo clase={'dark'} title={'Cobertura'} />
<Objetivo clase={'secondary'} title={'Aprobación'} />
```

Y que la clase cambie a `bg-dark` o `bg-secondary` o cualquier color que se le pase como valor en la propiedad `clase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prodrias usar [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) al definir la propiedad `className`, asi:

```
    <Col className={`bg-${this.props.clase} text-light p-3`}>
      <h4 className="text-white">{this.props.title}</h4>
    </Col>
```

Answer (score 1):

Trata de manejarlo con el **state** o con los **props** , con tu código y los states quedaria algo asi:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react'
    import { Row, Col } from 'reactstrap'

    class Objetivo extends Component {

      constructor (props) {
       super(props)

       this.state = {
        clase: "bg-dark text-light p-3"
       };
     }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="objetivos-portada">
            <Col className={this.state.clase}>
              <h4 className="text-white">{this.props.title}</h4>
            </Col>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

ó

```
        import React, {Component} from 'react'
        import { Row, Col } from 'reactstrap'

        class Objetivo extends Component {

          constructor (props) {
           super(props)

           this.state = {
            clase: "dark"
           };
         }

          render() {
            return (
              <div className="objetivos-portada">
                <Col className={`bg-${this.props.clase} text-light p-3`}>
                  <h4 className="text-white">{this.props.title}</h4>
                </Col>
              </div>
            )
          }
        }
```

Cuando hagas un evento que puedas actualizar el state colocas la otra clase, imaginate que llamas a una función que lo actualice como:

```
actualizarBg = () => {
    this.setState({
      clase: "primary"
    });
  }
```